# how to call a php script from jquery from html page

Tags: php, jquery, call

probably I'm sinking in an empty glass or maybe i've spent too many hours on this project, but here it goes: i want to call a php script using jquery from an htm file.

my jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "localhost/calculate/vr4/getAmount.php",
    data: "from="+ from_date +"&enddate=" + end_date,
    success: function(info){
        alert("test info : " + info);
    }
});
```

php script:

```
$testdate=$_POST['from'];

if ($testdate==NULL)
{
echo "No text";
}
else
{
echo "a date";
}
```

and nothing happends, and i noticed this in the url:

```
http://localhost/calculate/vr4/summary_q.php?consult_range.x=30&consult_range.y=5
```

those parameters (consult_range) is the class name for which i have bind the click event with jquery. any pointers?. I've tried several code examples from this forum and others and i get the same results. Hope someone answers, i know is kind of late

Comment: Get firebug and see what is called

Comment: It looks like the `from_date` variable is empty. Try to hardcode the parameters and see what happens. e.g: `data: "from=blah&enddate=blahblah",`.

Comment: add  http to url localhost/calculate/vr4/getAmount.php"

Comment: I think you mean `url: "/calculate/vr4/getAmount.php"` to be the url unless you actually have a path named localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/calculate/vr4/getAmount.php",
    data: "from="+ from_date +"&enddate=" + end_date,
    success: function(info){
        alert("test info : " + info);
    }
});

or

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vr4/getAmount.php",
    data: "from="+ from_date +"&enddate=" + end_date,
    success: function(info){
        alert("test info : " + info);
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data in GET format and I guess since you are using $_POST in php, you are getting an error because there is no Post data. At ajax call you need to pass the data as an object I think. But just to check if I'm rigth change $_POST to $_GET

Update

In your ajax call cange data with

`data: {from: from_date, enddate: end_date}`